# sufficient condition vs necessary condition

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, logic-translation

First sentence:

> If you live in Los Angeles, then you live in California

Second sentence:

> If you don't live in California, then you don't live in Los Angeles.

I am not sure, but I would like to say that the first sentence is NOT a sufficient condition because it is necessary you must live in Los Angeles to live in California.

Is it correct that the first sentence is NOT a sufficient condition, and the second sentence IS a necessary condition?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - I don't think this question is a duplicate of [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3614873/288417). Of course, they are related, but here the problem is that the OP doesn't understand that being a necessary or sufficient condition is a relative property, not an absolute one. This aspect of the question is completely absent in the other question, in my opinion.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256171/what-is-the-difference-between-necessary-and-sufficient-conditions) as well as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119592/difference-between-necessary-and-necessary-but-not-sufficient).

Comment: And obviously you can read [Wiki's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency).

Comment: @Betty. You may accept answer in case you consider it has been helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Being a sufficient or  necessary condition is not an *absolute* property but a *relative* property. 
A proposition is a sufficient or necessary condition *for another* proposition, not in and of itself. 
So, saying "the first sentence is (or is not) a necessary condition" is meaningless, without saying *for what* it is (or it not) a necessary condition. The same for sufficient condition.

In general, in a statement of the form $A \to B$ ("if $A$ then $B$", where $A$ and $B$ are propositions), we say that $A$ is a *sufficient* condition for $B$, and that $B$ is a *necessary* condition for $A$. 
Note that, in particular, saying that $A$ is a sufficient condition for $B$ is *equivalent* to say that $B$ is a necessary condition for $A$.

In your first sentence, the structure is $A \to B$, where

- $A$ is "living in Los Angeles",
- $B$ is "living in California".

So, according to the first sentence, "living in Los Angeles" is a sufficient condition for "living in California", and "living in California" is a necessary condition for "living in Los Angeles".

The structure of your second sentence is $\lnot B \to \lnot A$, which is logically equivalent to $A \to B$, therefore you can conclude the same thing as in the first sentence.

Comment: So, if I understand right, the first sentence expresses a sufficient condition. And the second sentence expresses a necessary condition.

Comment: What do you mean by first sentence?

Comment: first sentence is "If you live in Los Angeles, then you live in California". second sentence is "If you don't live in California, then you don't live in Los Angeles."

Comment: @betty - No, the first sentence says that "living in Los Angeles" is a sufficient condition for "living in California", and "living in California" is a necessary condition for "living in Los Angeles".

Comment: @Betty. You may accept answer in case you consider it has been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The *whole* sentence

> If you live in Los Angeles, then you live in California

is not a sufficient condition. Rather, you can say that this sentence expresses that living in Los Angeles is a sufficient condition for living in California. Or, in terms of sentences (or claims or propositions) , you can say that the sentence/claim/proposition

> you live in Los Angeles

is a sufficient condition for the sentence/claim/proposition

> you live in California

Likewise, the *whole* sentence:

> If you don't live in California, then you don't live in Los Angeles.

is *not* a sufficient or necessary condition all by itself ... Rather, this sentence expresses that living in California is a necessary condition for living in Los Angeles. Or again, in terms of sentences, the sentence/claim/proposition

> you live in California

is a necessary condition for the sentence/claim/proposition

> you live in Los Angeles

In sum, it's not that the first sentence is a sufficient condition, but rather that it expresses a sufficient condition relationship: that one thing is a sufficient condition for something else. Likewise, it's not that the second sentence is a necessary condition, but rather that it expresses a necessary condition relationship: that one thing is a necessary condition for something else.

And finally, a technical note: while any 'if $P$ then $Q$' sentence is indeed most naturally interpreted as expressing a sufficient condition relationship, namely that $P$ is a sufficient condition for $Q$, it can also be seen as expressing a necessary condition relationship: that $Q$ is necessary for $P$. For example, suppose I say: "If you have taken Calculus II, then you have taken Calculus I".  Why do you think I am able to say that? It's because I know that taking Calculus I is a necessary condition for Calculus II.

Likewise, while any 'if not $Q$ then not $P$' sentence is indeed most naturally interpreted as expressing a necessary condition relationship, namely that $Q$ is a sufficient condition for $P$, it can also be seen as expressing a sufficient condition relationship: that $P$ is sufficient for $Q$.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method :

(1) first , rephrase the sentence you are dealing with using the $\rightarrow$ notation.

Note :

- " if A then B " gives : $(A\rightarrow B)$
- " B, if A " also gives $(A\rightarrow B)$
- " A, only if B " also gives $(A\rightarrow B)$
- " not B , if not A " gives : ( $\neg A \rightarrow \neg B$), which is equivalent, by contraposition , 
  to ( $B \rightarrow A$).

(2) ***everything*** that comes ***before*** the arrow is a ***sufficient condition*** of ***the whole thing that  comes after*** the arrow ( provided the whole conditional  sentence is a true one, unless the " sufficient condition" is only an " alledged sufficient condition").

So ,

- in " ( you live in LA $\rightarrow$  you live in California) " the sentence " you live in LA" is a sufficient condition of " you live in California"
- in " ( you do not live in LA $\rightarrow$  you do not live in California) " the sentence " you do not live in LA" is a sufficient condition of " you do not live in California"

(3) ***everything*** that comes ***after***  the arrow is a ***necessary  condition of the whole thing that comes before*** the arrow ( provided the whole conditional sentence is a true one, unless the " necessary  condition" is only an " alledged necessary condition").

So ,

- in " ( you live in LA $\rightarrow$  you live in California) " the sentence " you live in California" is a necessary condition of " you live in LA"
- in " ( you do not live in LA $\rightarrow$  you do not live in California) " the sentence " you do not live in California" is a necessary condition of " you do not live in LA"

Note : a good thing to do is to get acquainted with the ***contrapositon*** rule, in order to perform transformations on conditional sentences; a conditional can be much clearer once transformed in a proper way