# How to translate English phrase "One can..." into FOL

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

The following predicate symbols are given:

- $J(x)$ translates to "$x$ is a serious jogger";
- $R(x)$ translates to "$x$ is a race";
- $T(x,y)$ translates to "$x$ takes part in race $y$".

How do we translate:

**"One can only be a serious jogger if one takes part in some race"**

I am having difficulty translating the word "one" which appears twice in the sentence above. Critique me on the following two efforts, i.e. how do they translate differently.

$\forall x \, (J(x) \to \exists y \, (R(y) \land T(x,y)))$

vs

$\exists x \,\exists y \, (J(x) \land R(y) \land T(x,y))$

Comment: No need to translate "can". It is "A only if B", i.e. $A \to B$

Comment: How did you get your second expression, $\exists x \exists y \ldots$?

Comment: My issue is with translating "one" and I thought it might be possible to translate "one" with $\exists$ as in "there is at least one". So "at least one" serious Jogger,x, and at least one race (translated from "some race"),y.

Comment: I see. I think the statement is supposed to use "one" as in "someone", i.e., anyone. So the stronger quantifier, $\forall$ would be more appropriate than $\exists$.

Comment: @Jam - agreed. Often my problem with translating these sentences comes down to the possible ambiguity of the English meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a native English speaker but in my opinion

> One can only be a serious jogger if one takes part in some race

means that "taking part in some race" is a *necessary* [condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3619235/288417) to "be a serious jogger", for *every* individual $x$.
Therefore, the logic form of the sentence above is 
\begin{align}
\forall x \, (J(x) \to \exists y \, (R(y) \land T(x,y))).
\end{align}
The "One" at the beginning of the sentence refers to a generic individual, so it is translated by the [universal quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification). "Some race" is clearly translated by the [existential quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification).